# Change the format of JavaScript Data object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data object as below:

```
[{"Positive":"14.71","Neutral":"50.0","Negative":"35.29"}]
```

I want to change this to the below specified format:

```
[{"type":"Positive","value":14.71},{"type":"Neutral","value":50.0},{"type":"Negative","value":35.29}]
```

Comment: you can do it by splitting the string and manually traverse through it

Comment: Did you try anything that you can show us?

Comment: I was trying to handle the data object in d3 js...

Comment: Ok, what did you try then?

Comment: Why is the input wrapped in an array ?

Comment: @naomik Thats actually the console output of the data object..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** methods.

```js
var data = [{
  "Positive": "14.71",
  "Neutral": "50.0",
  "Negative": "35.29"
}];

var res = Object.keys(data[0]) // get all object property names
  // iterate over property names array
  .map(function(k) {
    // generate array element using property value
    return {
      type: k,
      // cast data value to number using plus-sign prefix(as per requirement)
      value: +data[0][k]
    }
  })

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @GilBaggio :  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

I solve this using a generic `pairs` function which will be useful for you when trying to `map`, `reduce`, or `filter` objects in JavaScript

```js
let input = [{"Positive":"14.71","Neutral":"50.0","Negative":"35.29"}];

let pairs = o =>
  Object.keys(o).reduce((acc,k) => [...acc, [k, o[k]]], []);

let output = pairs(input[0]).map(([type,value]) =>
  ({type, value: Number(value)}));

console.log(output);
```

Alternatively, `pairs` can be implemented as a generator which will produce an overall more readable result

```js
let input = [{"Positive":"14.71","Neutral":"50.0","Negative":"35.29"}];

function* pairs(o) {
  for (let k of Object.keys(o))
    yield [k, o[k]];
}

let output = Array.from(pairs(input[0]), ([type, value]) => {
  return {type, value: Number(value)};
});

console.log(output);
```

`Array.from` provides a convenient way to collect values from an *iterable* value (and optionally *map* over them too), but you don't have to use it if you don't want to. Before you become familiar with it, you could just as easily use a `for-of` loop to collect the key/value pairs into your output object.

```js
let input = [{"Positive":"14.71","Neutral":"50.0","Negative":"35.29"}];

function* pairs(o) {
  for (let k of Object.keys(o))
    yield [k, o[k]];
}

let output = [];
for (let [type, value] of pairs(input[0]))
  output.push({type, value: Number(value)});

console.log(output);
```